# AFNetworking unable to download multiple m4a files in ios iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, afnetworking

I have an iPad app that downloads music files, m4a, from a server. I'm using AFHTTPRequestOperation to download directly to my doc dir uisng outputStreamToFileAtPath. I'm not concerned about how long it takes. I just need the files downloaded as the downloads will most likely take place after hours. I get the following error message when I try to run it on my ipad. I do get the first 5 and the last 5 but then the rest time-out. Is there a problem wit my code? Is there a way to increase the time-out value? Or is there something else I can use besides AFNetworking? Any help/ideas is greatly appreciated.

> ERROR ERROR ERROR:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0xc6e01c0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xxxx/Music/ece0b7c5ab71a24c6f6694986fc7a4a7.m4a, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxx/Music/ece0b7c5ab71a24c6f6694986fc7a4a7.m4a, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0xc69c950 "The request timed out."} - could not save to path:/var/mobile/Applications/207B2EFB-78E0-4BB2-8019-026B598ECE44/Documents/music/ece0b7c5ab71a24c6f6694986fc7a4a7.m4a

and the code:

```
- (void)saveFilesToDocDir
{
    NSString *fileLink = @"http://xxx/Music/";
    NSArray *dirPathSearch = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirPath = [dirPathSearch objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dirPath = [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"music/"];

    // if the sub directory does not exist, create it
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dirPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@: does not exists...will attempt to create", dirPath);

        if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error])
        NSLog(@"errormsg:%@", [error description]);
    }

    self.processCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.musicFiles count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *filename = [self.musicFiles objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fileLink, filename];
        NSString *filePath = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

        // download the song file and save them directly to docdir
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPath]];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
        {
            self.processCount++;
            NSLog(@"Song:%d Success!", processCount);

            // all the files have been saved, now update the playlist
            if (self.processCount == [self.musicFiles count])
            {
                [self updatePlaylist];
            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
        {
            self.processCount++;
            NSLog(@"ERROR ERROR ERROR:%@ - could not save to path:%@", error, filePath);
        } ];

        [operation start];
    }
```

Comment: ended up using an NSOperationQueue - it's slow but works.

Comment: I'm encountering the same situation but am using AFNetworking's AFHTTPClient's operationQueue. Any further ideas as to why when I enqueue a long list of streaming download operations many of them time out with this -1001 error?

Comment: I added [request setTimeoutInterval:900] to my NSMutableURLRequest. This fixed my problem. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks LittlePeculiar, were you seeing the same behavior? Ie timeouts? Thankfully your suggestion *seems* to have resolved the issue for me as well. I'm still interested in the root cause though. Could this be a result of multiple concurrent operations being started, and one is a video for example, and it consumes most of the streaming traffic for a period of time and the other in-progress operations time out? Or are these operations timing out before they're even started?

Comment: One more oddity: some of these timed out requests never even appear in Charles Proxy, as if the request "timed out" before it was even made.

Comment: I thought it was the multiple concurrent operation as well. I was downloading over 1000 m4a files, not huge files but big enough. I played with the maxConcurrentOperationCount until I got the most optimum download and moved on. Sorry I can't give you a better answer. Be interested to know what you find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
[request setTimeoutInterval:1000];
```

Set an appropriate value for interval(may use this), add it after request creation.